# I hit my head. It hurt. It hurt

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

He was playing beside the table.

He accidentally hit his head on the table.

"**I hit my head.**" he told me.

Does it sound natural to a native speaker?

Comment: We need more information before we can provide a useful answer. Please use the [edit] link to tell us what you do not understand about the sentence _"I hit my head."_ Why do you think it might not sound natural to a native speaker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**I hit my head**" is absolutely correct and sounds natural to me *(I'm not a native speaker)*.

> When someone hits their head it's an injury. Someone can hit their head on a something. Someone can also hit the back, the side or the front of their head. Or someone can be hit to the back, the side or the front of their head. Here are a few examples:

- I **hit the side of my head** when I fell. Now I have a bump there.
- Mary **hit her head** on the door-frame and now she has a concussion.
- Ludwig **was hit to the back of his head**. He has a terrible pain.

Here are [Google results](https://www.google.ru/search?q=I%20hit%20my%20head&oq=I%20hit%20my%20head&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1863j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=%22hit%20my%20head%22). Here is a [Google Books search](https://www.google.ru/search?q=I%20hit%20my%20head&oq=I%20hit%20my%20head&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1863j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22hit%20my%20head%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks).

Here's the chart: 
[image: hit * head]

Comment: No idea who the punk is who's downvoting you, but you're correct. Good show with the ngram.

Answer (score -1):

## Yes

It's so natural to describe *causing an injury to oneself by making contact with something* as *hitting oneself* that you already used the phrasing in your description of it. There are other languages where *hitting the ball* and *hitting your head* use two separate verbs, but English isn't one of them.

Now, that said, it'd be more natural to say "OW!" or "GODDAMMIT!" or "OOPS!" than to describe what you just did... but maybe you were looking at him questioningly.